# Displaying the optional note from a versioned entry

Tags: entrymodel

I want to use the note that is optional when saving a versioned entry as part of an activity feed -- like a git commit message.

Is there an entry model property for this?

Answer (score 5):

Indeed... [EntryModel->revisionNotes](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/models/EntryModel.php#L259) is what you're looking for.

Through PHP, that's:

```
$entry->revisionNotes
```

Through a template, that's:

```
{{ entry.revisionNotes }}
```

Comment: Thanks, Brad. Is there a way to access that through a template tag? I tried variations of {{ entry.getAttribute('revisionNotes') }} without any luck.

Comment: `{{ entry.revisionNotes }}` should do it.

Comment: @BradBell I have trouble getting this to work:
`{% set myEntry = craft.entries.section('myEntries').first %}`
`{{ myEntry.revisionNotes }}`

Even though the entry in question has a revision note, nothing comes up.

Comment: Hi, @BradBell. I know this is five years old and things have most likely changed, but when using your template code, I get this error: Getting write-only property: craft\elements\Entry::revisionNotes. Are revision notes no longer viewable in templates?

Answer (score 1):

At least for Craft 3.x, `revisionNotes` element property is protected and PHPDoc flagged as write-only: `@property-write`. But you can access the `$entry->revisionNotes` using a [Closure::call](https://www.php.net/manual/en/closure.call) or in combination with an [arrow function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php)

Closure::call PHP 7.0+

```
echo (function() {return $this->revisionNotes;})->call($entry);
```

Arrow Function PHP 7.4+

```
echo (fn() => $this->revisionNotes)->call($entry);
```